# CSS: remove separator on the last and first item

Tags: css, xhtml, menu

I have a menu div which has a dark background. Inside it, I have several menu item divs with 1px margins on the right and the left. This way I've got separators between them. Obviously these appear on the very left and very right side of the menu which I don't want. Is there a way to accomplish this without inserting 1-pixel divs as separators?

Thank you

edit: sorry, I thought it was descriptive enough. Here is the code:

```
<div id="menu">
       <a href="#"><div class="menu_item"><img src="imgs/menu/szabalyzat.png" /></div></a>
       <a href="#"><div class="menu_item"><img src="imgs/menu/profil.png" /></div></a>
       <a href="#"><div class="menu_item"><img src="imgs/menu/zenekarok.png" /></div></a>
       <a href="#"><div class="menu_item"><img src="imgs/menu/jelentkezes.png" /></div></a>
       <a href="#"><div class="menu_item"><img src="imgs/menu/esemenynaptar.png" /></div></a>
       <a href="#"><div class="menu_item"><img src="imgs/menu/mmmk_estek.png" /></div></a>
 </div>
```

IE6 incompatibility is OK (thankfully).

Comment: showing us some code would be nice, as we can only assume what you mean have so far.

Comment: putting divs inside links is not good.

Comment: n1313: If I don't, only the images are clickable and they are smaller than the actual divs.

Comment: By positioning the links appropriately, you shouldn't need the divs. something like: .menu a { display: block; width: 100px; float: left; }

Comment: You have to put an `alt` attribute to your images, so some text shows up if images can't be loaded or displayed, if you don't your menu won't be usable in this case. (+ it's mandatory to be standard compliant).

Comment: Allain: Thx, I cleaned up that piece of code. 
p4bl0: I know, it's there, I just removed it from here for the sake of readability. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you have 2px left-margin instead of 1px on each side and then use the css pseudo class `:first-child` to remove these margin for the first item ?

EDIT: I agree with the fact that you should use border as separator rather than background but in case you do this that way for some good reasons, my answer's still valid :-)

Comment: Well, I'm inexperienced with CSS, and didn't think of borders for this purpose. I had the #menu div and this was the firs solution that came into my mind. Do borders have some advantage over this solution?

Comment: borders are just a more "clean" way of doing this, since a border is already a kind of separator.

Answer (score 13):

The following rule will apply to all .menu_item  elements that follow another .menu_item  element:

```
.menu_item + .menu_item {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: hey! more pretty than my `:first-child` way!

Comment: Doesn anyone still use IE6? jk

Comment: Microsoft still support it, however even alexa big names are dropping support

Comment: It won't work in IE... So what? That's not something really important, it's just a small design polishing. As long as the website is usable with every browser it's okay for me. It's not a 20 by 2 px black rectangle that will scare IE6 users... If that was the case most of them would already be dead by heart-attack ^^.

Comment: this was sure prettier than :first-child, but it didn't work for me in ff3.5 (it's possible that I did something wrong though).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way yo achieve it is to mark your first and last elements with custom classes and remove that margins from them.

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="first">One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li class="last">Four</li>
</ul>
<style>
  .menu li { margin: 0 1px; }
  .menu .first { margin-left: 0; }
  .menu .last { margin-right: 0; }
</style>
```

You can also try using complex css selectors, like `:first-child`, but they do not work in older versions of MSIE.

OR, you can use 2px margins on the right side instead and go with only one additional class:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li class="last">Four</li>
</ul>
<style>
  .menu li { margin-right: 2px; }
  .menu .last { margin-right: 0; }
</style>
```

Comment: I corrected the margin in the first example, `1px 0` puts the margin on the top/bottom, not left/right as it should be. Also "none" is not a valid value AFAIK so I replaced with 0.

Answer (score 2):

If a high percentage of your audience's browsers support CSS3, you can use the [`:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo-classes](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html):

```
div#menu div:first-child {
margin-left: none;
}
div#menu div:last-child {
margin-right: none;
}
```

Comment: I think first and last-child are actually CSS2. Most browser support them, I think only ie6 does not (again).